# Text and ruby on one line using SLIM

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, slim-lang

I keep writing markup that looks like this:

```
span.label.label-default
   span < 
   span= (@today - 1.day).strftime("%e %B, %Y")
```

Supposed to come out looking like: `< 2 May, 2015`. I suppose I could write

```
span.label.label-default= "< #{(@today - 1.day).strftime('%e %B, %Y')}"
```

Is there a more optimal way to include text and ruby inside the same html tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not this:

```
span.label.label-default= (@today - 1.day).strftime("< %e %B, %Y")
```

Comment: Very clever in this particular case. But what if I didn't have convenient .strftime formatter and instead it was like `fetch_some_data()` instead?

Comment: In think string interpolation in Rails is already elegant :D If you have a complex render logic in view, you should move it to a helper or a presenter instead leave it in your view ;) read more here: http://mixandgo.com/blog/the-beginner-s-guide-to-rails-helpers and here http://nithinbekal.com/posts/rails-presenters/

Comment: Agreed with @Long. This situation is exactly what string interpolation is designed for.

Comment: The mixandgo.com link is broken. Use this instead: https://mixandgo.com/blog/the-beginners-guide-to-rails-helpers